# Cannot refresh the particular div which contains the php code using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to reload some content present inside the div but it can not happen like this. I am providing my code below.

space.php:

```
<?php
 require_once('header.php');
?>
<div>
    <a href="#">Update the div!</a>
</div>
```

header.php:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navmenu loadListSpaceDiv" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
<?php
  if(isset($_SESSION['vendor_id'])){ ?>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
        <li><a href="<?php echo SITEURL.'vendor';?>">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo SITEURL;?>signout">Sign Out</a></li>
    </ul>
<?php
}
?>
</div>
```

Here when user will click on `anchor tag` the above div element should refresh/reload. Here is my code:

```
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
        $(".loadListSpaceDiv").load(document.URL +  '.loadListSpaceDiv');
    });
});
```

But its not working as per expected. Here I need when user will click on that `a` tag the all div content will reload again.

Comment: `$(".loadListSpaceDiv")[0]` since you are using class as selector i think.

Comment: Yes,I am using class as selector.

Comment: Have you tried   $(".loadListSpaceDiv").load(document.URL);

Comment: @ProgrammerV5 : It will reload the total page. I need to load only that section present inside div.Actually I have also other code in that file.

Comment: By any chance is the space.php file on another domain?

Comment: It won't because you are doing a load on div (you can be more specific if you specify an ID instead of a class), if you are getting the entire page reloaded then you are having other issues (the selector is not working as expected).

Comment: Then what is the expected solution can you please share ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd wish to jQuery `load()` only a specific part of the source page, separate the CSS selector from the URL by a space:

```
$(".loadListSpaceDiv").load(document.URL +  ' .loadListSpaceDiv');
```